# Converting a double with two decimal points

Tags: c#, string, double

When I run this code in my project or in an online compiler like https://rextester.com/ I get an unexpected (wrong?) result:

```
var result = 0.0;
if (double.TryParse("20..3", out result)) Console.WriteLine(result);
```

> 203

I would expect that TryParse would return false. Oddly enough the code runs fine (with the expected result) on the machine of my college (with the exception of the online compiler of cause).

Why does this happen and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What cultures are you and your colleague running on? In some languages, the `.` is used as a thousand separator (`,` is used for decimal). Maybe that could be the cause?

Comment: Not reproducible https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Z2czF. Or I am missing something. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Are you sure 20..3 is not the range of integers from 20 to 3?

Comment: Tried on my Visual Studio and also can't reproduce. Must be some issue with your online compiler.

Comment: Are you from Germany or Austria by chance? Parsing with German and Austrian `CultureInfo` results in `203`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `double.Parse()` allows any number of thousands separators in any position.

Therefore, in cultures where the thousands separator is a `.`, it will parse OK.

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string test = "20..3";

            Console.WriteLine(double.TryParse(test, NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("en-GB"), out _)); // false
            Console.WriteLine(double.TryParse(test, NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("de-DE"), out _)); // true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to always fail on `..`, call the `Parse` method with an explicit `CultureInfo`, for exampe:

```
if (double.TryParse("200..03", NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("en-Us") ,out result))
```

By experimenting around, Austrian and German `CultureInfo` will result in a successful conversion, for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
var result = 0.0;
string real = "20..3";
if (double.TryParse(real.Replace("..","."), out result)) Console.WriteLine(result);
```

> if (double.TryParse(("20..3").Replace("..","."), out result))  works
>   as well

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Preview?url=/Widget/fG3byt